# FloatingActionButton above keyboard and BottomNavigationView hidden under keyboard in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, bottomnavigationview, floating-action-button, window-soft-input-mode

I'm faced with a problem I just can't wrap my head around. It's fairly straight forward;

I have a view in which I have an `EditText`, a `FloatingActionButton` and a `BottomNavigationView`. When I select the `EditText` the keyboard pops up. This is when I want the `FloatingActionButton` to *float above* the keyboard and the `BottomNavigationView` to stay *hidden* behind the keyboard.

I have tried using both `android:windowSoftInputMode` as `adjustResize` and as `adjustPan`. The former will make the `FloatingActionButton` *and* the `BottomNavigationView` stay hidden behind the keyboard. The latter will push both the `FloatingActionButton` and the `BottomNavigationView` up above the keyboard.

In addition to this I tried using a simple *custom* `BottomNavigationView` element that set it's own `visibility` to `hidden` when the keyboard is detected (using *viewTreeObserver* and *addOnGlobalLayoutListener*). This works in tandem with `adjustResize`, but there is a slight delay after the kayboard pops up where you can see the `BottomNavigationView`, making it look very "jumpy".

My question is now; Are there are alternative solutions to this?

*Edit*
This is my current xml, it's very straight forward.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/navigation"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="right"/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You want FloatingActionButton to float above the keyboard and the BottomNavigationView to stay hidden behind the keyboard

Comment: please provide your xml layout code

Comment: @Khemraj yes, word by word what my post says :)

Comment: @HiteshSarsava I added the xml

Answer (score 1):

The one thing that i use always to get rid of this problem.

1. Wrap your view inside ScrollView that you dont want to come up of keyboard.
2. Keep views outside Scrollview which you want float upon keyboard when keyboard opens.

**Does not this sounds good and pretty easy :)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_next"
        android:background="#0ff"
        >
       // these views will not come up.
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
                android:hint="Hint"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABC"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    // this will float on keyboard
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Button Next"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in the manifest.xml

```
<application
        ...
        >
        <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
           >
        </activity>
</application>
```

**Edit:**

Try this, it is used to move fab upon keyboard.

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your activity in manifest
Make sure your root view in layout xml, has `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` property

Comment: I fail to see solve how this will solve my problem, am I supposed apply this code to my problem. What `Window Soft Input Mode` should I use?

Comment: See new edit answer, let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

change your main parent layout property `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` to `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and put `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: By doing this the FAB does indeed move up, but so does the BottomNavigationView, which is undesirable.

Comment: have you removed your viewTreeObserver and addOnGlobalLayoutListener  from activity? and as per your xml layout design you given its working perfectly for me . @RasmusIsraelsson

Comment: Yes the viewTreeObserver has never been used on this specific example. Can you provide screenshots of the result of your solution?